# Mensagem de sucesso com ajax com validação boostrap 4

Tags: ajax, validation

Eu tenho esse código que funciona perfeitamente. Na pagina `cadastrarFuncionario.php` são feitos um INSERT no banco e um upload de uma imagem e caso haja sucesso no upload tem um `echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";` que é apresentado na `<div id="documento_e"></div>` do HTML

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // evento de "submit"
    $("#botaoCad").click(function (e) {
        // parar o envio para que possamos faze-lo manualmente.
        e.preventDefault();
        // captura o formulário
        var form = $('#form_funcionario')[0];
        // cria um FormData {Object}
        var data = new FormData(form);
        // processar
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "processosPHP/cadastrarFuncionario.php",
            data: data,
            processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
            contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
            cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
            // manipular o sucesso da requisição
            success: function (data) {
                $("#documento_e").html(data);
            },
            // manipular erros da requisição
            error: function (e) {
                $("#documento_e").html(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Coloquei nele uma validação boostrap 4

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // evento de "submit"
        $("#botaoCad").click(function(event) {
                // Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation
                var form = $("#form_funcionario")

                if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
                  event.preventDefault()
                  event.stopPropagation()
                }else{   
                    // cria um FormData {Object}
                    var data = new FormData(form[0]);
                    // processar
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        url: "processosPHP/cadastrarFuncionario.php",
                        data: data,
                        processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
                        contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
                        cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
                        // manipular o sucesso da requisição
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#documento_e").html(data);
                        },
                        // manipular erros da requisição
                        error: function (e) {
                            $("#documento_e").html(e);
                        }
                    });


            }
            form.addClass('was-validated');

        });
    });
```

nesse caso, tanto o INSERT quanto o upload são executados, porém, não aparece a mensagem `Upload efetuado com sucesso!` na `<div id="documento_e"></div>` do HTML

OBS: O arquivo `cadastrarFuncionario.php` é exatamente o mesmo para os dois casos.

Como poderia ser apresentado uma mensagem no segundo caso?

Comment: Dando um `alert` ou um `console.log` na resposta aparece algo?

Comment: @edsonalves não

Comment: Já saquei. Acho que a resposta do Andrei resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema, ao meu ver, é que você está colocando a `preventDefault()` dentro do `if`. Quando seu código entra no `else` o `preventDefault()` não é acionado, alterando o estado atual e não mostrando a `div` com mensagem de sucesso. Na verdade a div é mostrada, mas de maneira tão rápida que não se vê pois logo depois o evento altera o estado atual.

Se você fizer isso dentro do `click`, irá funcionar normalmente, como antes:

```
event.preventDefault();
  if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
      event.stopPropagation()
    }else{   
        // cria um FormData {Object}
        var data = new FormData(form[0]);
        // processar
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "processosPHP/cadastrarFuncionario.php",
            data: data,
            processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
            contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
            cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
            // manipular o sucesso da requisição
            success: function (data) {
                $("#documento_e").html(data);
            },
            // manipular erros da requisição
            error: function (e) {
                $("#documento_e").html(e);
            }
        });

    }
```